# When phoning, is there some way to 'say' the digits to a menu system in stead of having to enter them on the keyboard

Tags: 2.2-froyo, calls, voice-command

On my Samsung Galaxy S (running Froyo) I was phoning my voice mail system, where I have to press *1 to hear the message*, *2 to erase the message* ... you know what I mean.

When choosing a number I constantly have to **remove the phone from my ear**, **enter a digit** and than (quickly) **put it to my ear again** to 'hear' the new menu options.

I was just wondering: **is there any way to say the digits , in stead of having to type them ?**

That would be handy no ? Maybe , you have to press one button to start the system, but even that is preferable to the current way.

Comment: as a workaround, you can also use earphone on these sort of situations.

Comment: Have you considered using a visual voicemail app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the problem with this is that your phone cannot distinguish between what you want to say and transmit to the other end of the conversation, and words you want to be commands to the phone.  What if you call an automated system that says "Say 'one' for X.  Say 'two' for Y."?  When you say 'one' or 'two', there's no way (without very advanced AI) for the phone to decide whether you intended to transmit that speech (e.g. "two") or intended it to be a command for the phone to dial ('2').

You could possibly have a custom dialer app where if you press a button on your phone, it stops transmitting your voice and accepts commands, and pressing again stops accepting commands and resumes transmitting your voice.  I'd bet a lot of money that no one has made such a custom dialer.

Of course, there are many phones where you can enter "pauses" into the dialer, followed by menu choices.  For example, 555-555-5555-PAUSE-PAUSE-PAUSE-2-PAUSE-1 will:

1. Dial 555-555-5555
2. Wait for the call to connect
3. Press '2' (for a menu option)
4. Wait for the next menu
5. Press '1' (for a menu option)

This might serve your needs if you know the menu layout, but otherwise I think you're stuck (unless you want to use headphones as Lie Ryan suggests).

Comment: Yes, I know the problem. I did mention in my question a button to be pressed before the phone knows what you mean when you say one, two .... You know: Star Trek's log system starts recording when you say 'Computer Log' or 'Computer resume', it doesn't record everything ... :)